# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lchirpconnect/SDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, proguard, chirp

I am using [Chirp](https://www.chirp.io/) **Android SDK** for sharing data over **sound**, its working pretty well.

But when I am enabling my **proguard** then this **JNI** exeption is **throwing**, i have tried many ways to overcome this issue like add **proguard rule** in proguard file lets see :

> -keep class io.chirp.connect.Chirpconnect { *; }
>
> -keep class chirpconnect.Chirpconnect { *; }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       native methods; }

But not found any solutions?

I have just added one chirp SDK **AAR** in a **libs** folder and add this

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

to **build.gradle** file

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment.

The class name is actually `io.chirp.connect.ChirpConnect` with a capital C for Connect. Does this solve the issue?

Comment: @Bijan: this answer may be wrong (I don't know either way), but it does appear to attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @MohitSuthar have you tried the starter project at https://github.com/chirp/chirp-connect-react-native-starter? Running ./gradlew assembleRelease with proguard enabled on this project builds successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this may it will helps you :-

```
-keep class io.chirp.connect.** { *; }
-keep class chirpconnect.** { *; }
-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```